# Help Showing a Relation is/isn't a Partial Order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

Define the relation $\le$, as $(a,b)\le(c,d)$ if and only if $a+b\le c+d$ and $a\le c$.

Is this a partial order?

I know it's definitely not if we remove the $a\le c$ (because then it's not antisymmetric - example (1,3) and (2,2)), but not sure how to show one way or another with that $a\le c$ tacked on. At first I thought it might simply be a weird way to write the lexicographic order, but that doesn't seem to be true. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\leq$ is a [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition), we need to show three things:

- $(a,b) \leq (a,b)$ for all $(a,b)$.
- $(a,b) \leq (c,d)$ and $(c,d)\leq (a,b)$ implies $(a,b) = (c,d)$.
- $(a,b)\leq (c,d)$ and $(c,d) \leq (e,f)$ then $(a,b) \leq (e,f)$.

The first definitely holds, as $a \leq a$ and $a + b \leq a + b$.

The second holds: Assume $(a,b) \leq (c,d)$ and $(c,d) \leq (a,b)$.  Then we have $a \leq c$ and $c \leq a$.  These two imply that $a = c$.  Additionally, we have $a + b \leq c + d$ and $c + d \leq a + b$.  These two imply that $a + b = c + d$.  However, since we already know that $a = c$, we can subtract $a$ from the left and $c$ from the right to see that $b = d$.  Thus, we have $(a,b) = (c,d)$.

Finally, the last holds; $(a,b) \leq (c,d) \leq (d,e)$ implies that $a \leq c \leq d$.  Moreover, $a + b\leq c + d \leq e + f$.  Thus $\leq$ is a partial order.

Comment: I think it's the second one that's giving me trouble, the antisymmetric rule. I know it's not antisymmetric if the $a\le c$ isn't there, but how would I show that it is when the $a\le c$ part of the definition? You say the the second holds, but I'm having trouble seeing what you've written support that claim.

Comment: Okay, I added a bit more.  Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Comment: My answer's basically the same as Marcus',so both should help.

Answer (score 2):

Reflexivity: Let $(a,b) \in R$. Then $(a,b) \leq (a,b)$ since a+b= a+b $\rightarrow$ a+b $\leq$ a+b and clearly $a\leq a$.

Antisymmetry:  Let $(a,b) \leq (c,d)$ and $(c,d) \leq (a,b)$. Then  $a+b \leq c+d $ and $a\leq c$. Also,  $c+d \leq a+b$ and $c\leq a$.  Clearly, c < a and a < c is a contradiction unless a= c. By the same reasoning since a=c,a+b < c+d and c+d < a+b is a contradiction unless a+b = c+d. But since a=c, this implies b=d.So by the definition of equal ordered pairs, $(a,b)= (c,d)$.

Transitivity:  This is a little tedious. Let $(a,b) \leq (c,d)$ and $(c,d) \leq (e,f)$. Then $a+b \leq c+d $ and $a\leq c$. Also,   $c+d \leq e+f $ and $c\leq e$. Then $a\leq c \leq e$ $\rightarrow$ $a\leq e$. So $a+b \leq c+d \leq e+f $ $\rightarrow$  $a+b \leq e+f $. So $(a,b) \leq (e,f)$ and this gives transitivity and we're done!

Comment: For antisymmetric, shouldn't it be $(c,d)\le (a,b)$? And thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you explain how $a+b=c+b$ and $c+d=a+d$, implies $b=d$? Might just be tiredness, but I'm not seeing something.

Comment: @Bob Yes,it should,my bad. Corrected both it and added details to antisymmetry which should clear it up since your brain isn't functioning right now-something I have a lot of experience with.........lol.